# NIZKs for hash functions

Tags: hash, zero-knowledge-proofs

Hash functions such as SHA are considered as non-algebraic statements. How can one construct a NIZK proof to show that the output of a hash is computed correctly in an efficient manner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example, one could rely on [ZKBoo](https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/163.pdf), which in turn builds upon the MPC-in-the-Head paradigm by Ishai et al. The authors even provide an [implementation](https://github.com/Sobuno/ZKBoo), which demonstrates how to prove knowledge of a SHA-1 and SHA-256 preimage, respectively. The proofs are of linear size in the number of AND gates in the circuit. For more compact proofs you could have a look at SNARKs.

The authors discuss $\Sigma$-protocols, which are in fact interactive. However, as shown [here](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/279.pdf) or [here](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/1154.pdf), one can make those proofs non-interactive using the Fiat-Shamir transform (yielding security in the random oracle model) or the Unruh transform (yielding security in the quantum accessible random oracle model).

Comment: Thanks for your reply! To prove knowledge of the pre-images in ZKBoo, the non-algebraic statement must be first expressed as a Boolean circuit.(I'm assuming this is not very efficient).  What is the difficulty in creating NIZKs for arithmetic circuits?

Comment: ZKBoo does not only work for binary circuits, but for arithmetic circuits over arbitrary rings. It heavily depends on the circuit which ring fits best.